# ping statistics time meaning

Tags: ping

```
# ping -c 3 amsterdam.voip.ms
PING amsterdam.voip.ms (37.58.88.242) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from f2.58.3a25.ip4.static.sl-reverse.com (37.58.88.242): icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=98.5 ms
64 bytes from f2.58.3a25.ip4.static.sl-reverse.com (37.58.88.242): icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=89.8 ms
64 bytes from f2.58.3a25.ip4.static.sl-reverse.com (37.58.88.242): icmp_seq=3 ttl=52 time=91.9 ms

--- amsterdam.voip.ms ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 89.827/93.439/98.558/3.720 ms
```

What does the "time 2001ms" mean? It doesn't seem to be related to the actual packet transmission times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `time` statistic is the total time spent sending and receiving echo packets, including the delay between each packet:

```
$ time ping 127.0.0.1
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.049 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.039 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.039 ms
^C
--- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 1998ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.039/0.042/0.049/0.007 ms

real    0m2.362s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
```

Comment: And `/usr/bin/time -v command` will show even more info, like page swaps, cpu cycles used, etc.

Comment: Mine says 7ms even though a 4 individual pings are each > 30ms?

Comment: @SilverlightFox https://serverfault.com/a/999645/53210