# Ping time is less than an individual ping

Tags: fedora, ping

As per the answer to [ping statistics time meaning](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/362890/67045)

> The `time` statistic is the total time spent sending and receiving echo packets, including the delay between each packet

However, my `time` result is much shorter. What gives?

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8 -c 10
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=31.10 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=32.7 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=53 time=33.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=53 time=36.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=53 time=40.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=6 ttl=53 time=50.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=7 ttl=53 time=34.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=8 ttl=53 time=146 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=9 ttl=53 time=30.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=10 ttl=53 time=123 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 10 received, 0% packet loss, time 21ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 30.910/55.950/146.332/39.970 ms
```

Why does it show 21ms at the end?

Comment: You should try also an mtr as well in order to see if there is a problem in a hop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is a bug in the current implementation of `iputils-ping`.
>   ([via](https://serverfault.com/questions/999595/what-does-the-time-field-indicate-in-ping-statistics))

See https://github.com/iputils/iputils/issues/193